# How to navigate to recycle bin through system level powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, forensics

I'm having difficulty navegating to the recycle bin on windows 10 machines through powershell.

I'm able to get &Recycle.Bin listed by using the force option on ls, but I can't change my directory to that path.

For this question I'm using a system level terminal, so I can't depend on the environment variables to lead me to my recycle bin. I'm going to want to gather everything in the recycle bin for every user, so I need the path to all user's recycle bin.

There are other posts on this topic, they all suggest solutions that no longer work in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> cd 'C:$Recycle.Bin'

I just needed quotes